# Different results of Junit Test in different IDEs

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans, junit, libs

```
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Test1 {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void main() throws Exception {
        SAXBuilder sax = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc = sax.build(new FileReader("resources/file.xml"));
        System.out.println(doc.getRootElement().getText());
    }
}
```

file.xml contains this:  `<root>©</root>` encoding is UTF-8.

Used libs jdom2-2.06, hamcrest-core-1.3, junit-4.11.

When I run this in IntelliJ output is such: `©`.

When I run this in NetBeans output is such: `Â©`.

If I put the code to public static void main and run it - everything is ok.

If I change FileReader to FileInputStream - everything is ok.

If I change FileReader to `StringReader("<root>©</root>")` - everything is ok.

What can it be?

Comment: Encoding issues.

Comment: Why IntelliJ is not affected with these issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not specifying a character set when reading the file, so it uses the JVM default, afaik running from IntelliJ usually defaults to UTF-8, while Eclipse (at least on Windows) defaults to the default non-unicode character set (eg Cp1252 in Western Europe).

You will need to be explicit, as described in the documentation of [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html):

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character
>   encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate. To specify
>   these values yourself, construct an InputStreamReader on a
>   FileInputStream.

In other words:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("resources/file.xml"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Or alternatively, let `SAXBuilder` handle this for you and just give it an `InputStream`. I believe - but I am not 100 % sure - this will determine character set by the XML declaration:

```
sax.build(new FileInputStream("resources/file.xml"))
```